# fgets in a CR-only text file

Tags: c, stdio

I'm trying to convert some old code. One part of the code uses `fgetc` to read a file character-by-character to find lines. `fgets` seems like a much clearer way to do this.

However, I suspect I will someday run across one delimited entirely by CR, with no LF's in sight. the `fgetc` solution solved this, but only at the cost of increased code complexity, and possibly slower performance.

Is there a trick I can use here? I've seen some clever use of `strtok` with "\n\r" but that seems... a little too tricky, and still leaves me with the problem of reading the line from the file.

Comment: Stick to the (f)getc. It allows you to read the string in one pass. (strlen would need an extra pass, so would strtok,strchr,strcspn,...) And the *clean* way is (fgets,...) `buff[strcspn(buff, "\r\n")] = 0;`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was just wondering if there was a trick - in C, there's almost always a trick!

Comment: To hide the complexity, you could write your own function similar to fgets() but handles any of CR/LF/CRLF.

Comment: @wildplasser - I just realized the brilliance of your comment! fgets with a string pass would actually be *slower* than going char-by-char. That was not obvious to me even after I read it once.

Comment: Also: don't underestimate the overhead of function calls. If speed is really important (it seldom is):  when possible,  use `getc()` instead of `fgetc()`. (assuming that getc is implemented as a macro). Or just use fgets() ...